# SQL subquery with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB column named `ask_code` and `ask_grouping` which says if the `ask_code` is grouping or not (like a boolean for G = yes). How I do a SELECT query to get all the `ask_code` by grouping?

Something like that:

```
| ask_code | ask_grouping | reference_id |
|   A1     |              |       1      |
|   TOTAL  |       G      |       1      |
|   AREA   |       G      |       1      |
|POPULATION|       G      |       1      |
|   A2     |              |       2      |
|   TOTAL  |       G      |       2      |
|   AREA   |       G      |       2      |
```

And I want:

```
| ask_code |   grouping   |
|   A1     |   TOTAL      |
|   A1     |   AREA       |
|   A1     |   POPULATION |
|   A2     |   TOTAL      |
|   A2     |   AREA       |
```

Comment: `SELECT ask_code, type as ask_grouping FROM db.asks WHERE ask_grouping='G'` ?

Comment: Let me re-do the question, a minute please

Answer (score 2):

There is no ordering defined, so the output is not in the desired order:

```sql
SELECT 
  m1.reference_id,
  m1.ask_code,
  m2.ask_code as ask_gropuing
FROM mytable m1
INNER JOIN mytable m2 ON m2.ask_grouping='G' and m2.reference_id=m1.reference_id
WHERE m1.ask_grouping is null
ORDER BY m1.reference_if,m1.ask_code;
```

output:

| reference_id | ask_code | ask_gropuing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | TOTAL |
| 1 | A1 | AREA |
| 1 | A1 | POPULATION |
| 2 | A2 | TOTAL |
| 2 | A2 | AREA |

I just left `reference_id` in the output, but that can be left out.  Still the ordering is unknown, so possibly incorrect.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ip_tO520)

Comment: @Barmar: I did change the answer, (but not the fiddle... )

Comment: How about if the reference_id it's a FK? I have to use another ```INNER JOIN```? Like ```INNER JOIN references ON references.reference_id = m1``` (or m2.reference_id?)```.reference_id```?

Comment: @null92: Sorry that was not in your question, and my knowledge on *foreign keys* is (voluntarily! ) limited.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with max window function as the following:

```
select grp as ask_code, ask_code as grouping_
from
(
  select ask_code, ask_grouping, reference_id,
     max(case when ask_grouping is null then ask_code end) over (partition by reference_id) as grp
  from table_name
) T
where ask_grouping='G'
order by grp, ask_grouping
```

[see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IZSfEWsR)